# How to declare a long long int array in C90

Tags: c, c89

I'm troubling with my C90 compiler as it's showing error in long long int. I want to declare an long long int type array.

Is there any other way to compile it with C90?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
    {
        int i,n,j,X;
        long long int N[60];
        N[0]=0;
        N[1]=1;
        for(i=2;i<61;i++)
        {
            N[i]=N[i-1]+N[i-2];
        }
        scanf("%d",n);
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
         scanf("%d",X);
         printf("Fib(%d) = %lld",X,N[X]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't unless your C90 compiler supports `long long` or otherwise supports 64-bit integral types as an extension.  Only a few real-world C90 compilers do that - but all C99 compilers do.  Alternatively, obtain a third-party library that supports larger integral types (but, in C, those will involve a distinct set of API functions for all math operations, as opposed to just using `+` for addition).    Also, even if you can find a compiler to accept it, the first loop runs past the end of the array, so will probably crash.  Classic "off by one" error.

Comment: @Peter: Support for "long long" among twentieth-century compilers may be limited, but especially in the embedded world there may be a fair number of compilers that support some C99 features without being fully C99-compliant.

Comment: Also, after the definition `long long int N[60];` you have 60 elements: `N[0]`, ...`N[59]`. Your loop tries to access `N[60]`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can find some non-standard pre-processor extension, then no you can't use `long long` in C90.

Though if you are lucky, the compiler implements `stdint.h` where you can find `int64_t`. Some C90 compilers like Visual Studio 2017 does this.

Given that great C99 or C11 compilers are available free of charge, for a whole lot of different systems, there should be no reasons to sticking with C90.

Comment: If one has a project that works with a particular C implementation, that fact in and of itself may be a good reason for continuing to use that implementation.